# AppScript - LanguageApp.translate fails for random dates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am using LanguageApp.translate to translate date from English(en) to Marathi(mr). It worked fine for `new Date()` (returns today's date which is 12 Apr 2022 in my case).

However, when I selected 10th of April, it did not translate the date. So I tried 13th April, it again worked. So I just put a loop through each date of that month to know what works and what doesn't it failed for very random numbers - 10, 11, 19, 20, 30.

I am not able to judge why the same code fails for few dates.

Here's looped code:

```
function dateTest(){
  
  for (var i = 1; i<=30; i++){
    var date2 = new Date(2022,3);
    date2.setDate(i);
    date2 = Utilities.formatDate(date2, "GMT+5.30", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    var marathi = LanguageApp.translate(date2, 'en', 'mr');
    Logger.log(marathi);
  }
}
```

and here's the part of result:

[image]

see how 10th and 11th aren't converted. I have already reported this to google however, checking here if I have missed something.

Comment: I think it has something to do with date formatting `"dd-MM-yyyy` gives different type of results then `dd/MM/yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good in your script, I tested it and got the same result, then I went to [translate.google.com](https://translate.google.com/) and the same happens through the UI. You can check [here](https://translate.google.com/?hl=en&sl=en&tl=mr&text=17-04-22%0A18-04-22%0A19-04-22%0A20-04-22%0A21-04-22%0A22-04-22%0A23-04-22%0A24-04-22%0A25-04-22%0A26-04-22%0A27-04-22%0A28-04-22%0A29-04-22%0A30-04-22&op=translate).

This might be an issue with Google Translate and not with your code, you can report this Google Translate issue through the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) so Google is aware of this behavior and provides a solution.

Comment: Yes, reported and they said it's an issue.